# Trilinear Interpolation in C#

Tags: c#, c++, interpolation

I need make Trilinear Interpolation in C#, I´ve been searching and I´ve found and example in C++.

the example is here: http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/33, but it is in C++.

I need and example in c# or Someboy who can translate the code to C#, becauase I have tried and I don´t known.

Comment: This question is off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a language conversion service.

Comment: I known it is not a language conversion service , but if somebody has an example in C# I would be very grateful. I´ve put this example as an example that I want.

Answer (score 3):

This is a close transliteration so you can understand, but it is **clearly not** good C# code.

```
public static class Interpolator
{
    public static double Linear(double target, params double[] values)
    {
        return target * values[0] + (1.0 - target) * values[1];
    }

    public static double Bilinear(double[] target, params double[] values)
    {
        var prime = new[]
        {
            Linear(target[1], values),
            Linear(target[1], values.Skip(2).Take(2).ToArray())
        };

        return Linear(target[0], prime);
    }

    public static double Trilinear(double[] target, params double[] values)
    {
        var prime = new[]
        {
            Bilinear(target, values),
            Bilinear(target.Skip(1).ToArray(), values.Skip(4).ToArray())
        };

        return Linear(target[2], prime);
    }
}
```

Note: Since C# has *generics* and not *templates*, it's not possible to generalize this code to type T. The C++ compiler can check at runtime that type T implements the required operators, but there is no C# type constraint that would let you substitute only numeric types to T. As the compiler can't resolve the operators, using generics is not possible here.

Comment: WARNING! I've just used the code provided and it's definitely invalid. ".Skip(1).ToArray()" should be erased! But that's ok for you)) the error originates from that awful c++ code TS found